# How to resolve error when running dynamic PostreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, dynamic-sql

I have a function that takes 3 parameters: `huc, id_list, and email`.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_app.job_batch(
    huc text,
    input_list text[],
    email text
 ) RETURNS VOID AS
 $$
 DECLARE
     id text;
 BEGIN
     FOREACH id IN ARRAY input_list LOOP
         EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM my_app.my_funct(
         ' || huc || '::text,
         ' || id || '::text,
         ' || email || '::text)';
     END LOOP;
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to run the function however, it throws an error: `ERROR: column "myhu4" does not exist`

```
SELECT * FROM spg_app.append_spg_job_batch('MYHUC4', array['1021', '1025','1026','1027','0701','0702','0703','0708','0709'], 'myemail@gmail.com');
```

Why is it referring to `myhuc4` as a column and why is displaying it in lower case. Is my syntax below to run the function with those 3 parameters incorrect? Note: If I run the below hardcoded version, it runs fine:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    id_list text[] := array['1021', '1025','1026','1027','0701','0702','0703','0708','0709'];
    id text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH id in ARRAY id_list LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM my_app.my_funct(
        ''MYHU4''::text,
        ' || id || '::text,
        ''myemail@gmail.com''::text)'
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: First difference between "dynamic" and "manual" versions - in  "dynamic" you use `text` data type for params, in "manual" -  `varchar`. This types are not the same. Second - in "manual" you enclose the textual values in apostrophes, but in "dynamic" - do not. And I think the second is the cause of error - without apostrophes `' || huc || '::text` will become `MYHUC4::text`, that's can be treated as a column name with conversion to `text` data type. The same issue with `' || email || '::text`

Comment: I just amended the code. Check my changes about the hardcoded version. Are you saying I need to add additional apostrophes? Or just remove the `text` casting when I plug in the parameters?

Comment: 1) Provide the code for `my_funct()`. 2) `column "myhu4" does not exist` is happening because the value for `huc` is being double quoted at some point e.g.  "myhu4" and that is being taken as a column identifier. This why we need to 1) to be done.

Comment: Why do you even use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in the first place? You do not want to construct a dynamic query here. Just `SELECT * FROM my_app.my_funct(huc, id, email);`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use parameters instead of bad practice of stitching strings, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_app.job_batch(
    huc text,
    input_list text[],
    email text
 ) RETURNS VOID AS
 $$
 DECLARE
     id text;
 BEGIN
     FOREACH id IN ARRAY input_list LOOP
         execute format ('SELECT * FROM my_app.my_funct($1, $2, $3)')
            using huc, id, email;
     END LOOP;
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

as shown in official docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: This actually worked quite well. I didn't realize `||` was the old way of doing things. This was much more compact. Thanks.